# How to select the closest data to the given time for each group

Tags: go, influxdb

I'm using InfluxDB 1.4, and here's my task

```
1) find the closet value for each IDs. 
2) Do 1) for every hour
```

For example,

```
select id, value, time from myTable where time = '2018-08-14T00:00:00Z' group by id;
select id, value, time from myTable where time = '2018-08-14T01:00:00Z' group by id;
....
select id, value, time from myTable where time = '2018-08-14T23:00:00Z' group by id;
```

then, some id have value at each o'clock but others don't. In this case, I want to get the closest row to the give time '2018-08-14T14:00:00Z', like as '2018-08-14T14:00:01Z' or '2018-08-14T13:59:59Z'

and I don't want to query 24 times for each hour. Can I do this task with group by time, id, or something else?

Comment: do you mind paraphrasing your question? What do you mean by `closest` value? Closest to?

Comment: I edited my question. What I want is to get the closest row to the given time. Before or after. Like '2018-08-14T14:00:01Z' or '2018-08-14T13:59:59Z'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Q:** I would like to `select` the point data closest to the hourly boundary. Is there a way I can do this without having to query 24 times for each day? Will `group by time` be any help on this?

**A:**

> Will `group by time` be any help on this?

Unfortunately the `group by time` function will not be much help to you as it  requires the query to have an aggregation function. What the `group by time` function does is that it groups all data that falls within the interval into one single record by using the `aggregation` function like `sum`, `mean` etc to tabulate the combined row's values.

> Is there a way I can do this without having to query 24 times for each
>   day?

To the best of my knowledge, I don't think `influxdb 1.5` has any way to build a one liner query for this task. Maybe there is something in `1.6`, i'm not sure. Haven't tried that.

At the moment I think your best solution today is to  build a query that uses the `time filter`, `order by` and `limit` functions e.g.

`select * from uv where time >= '2018-08-18T14:00:00Z' and time < '2018-08-18T15:00:00Z' order by desc limit 1;`

The query above means that you are `selecting` all the points within 2pm to 3pm and then order them by descending order but only return the first row, which is what you want.

If for some reason you can only do 1 HTTP request to influxdb for the hourly data on a particular day. You can bundle up the 24 queries into one big query using the `;` seperator and retrieve the data in 1 transaction. E.g.

`select * from uv where time >= '2018-08-18T14:00:00Z' and time < '2018-08-18T15:00:00Z' order by desc limit 1; select * from uv where time >= '2018-08-18T15:00:00Z' and time < '2018-08-18T16:00:00Z' order by desc limit 1; select * from uv where time >= '2018-08-18T16:00:00Z' and time < '2018-08-18T17:00:00Z' order by desc limit 1;`

**Output:**

```
name: uv
time                tag1 id         value
----                -------- --         -----
1534603500000000000 apple  uv 2
1534607100000000000 apple  uv 1
1534610700000000000 apple  uv 3.1
```

Comment: Thank you for kind answer. Actually I did in the similar way. But since it took too long for me, I wanted to know better method. :)

Comment: @JihuiChoi no worries. Have you explored `Kapacitor`? Because you can pre-process the data using it and write it out to another measurement, that way your application can simply `select` the data without having to go through the explained hassle.

Comment: nope. In the company, we use influxdb only with our own tool. but I guess I should try it whether I can use it with our data or not. thank you.